# What is an irreducible matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I came upon this definition:

> ${\bf Def.}$ A matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is said to be
>    *irreducible* if and only if for any two distinct indices $1\le i,j\le n$, there is a sequence of nonzero elements of $A$ of the form $$
>  \{a_{ii_1},a_{i_1i_2},\ldots,a_{i_mj}\}. $$

Which I cannot understand. Could someone elaborate on  that and give an example?

Comment: I cannot understand that, either. Aren't there some examples_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A directed graph is called strongly connected if every vertex is reachable from every other vertex. If you view $A$ as the matrix for a directed graph, where node $k$ is connected to node $l$ by a directed arc if and only if $a_{kl}\ne0$, then what the definition says is that the graph itself is strongly connected. Therefore, it cannot be broken into smaller strongly connected components and that's why it is called irreducible.

E.g. $\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}$ is irreducible while $\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&1}$ is reducible (node 2 is reachable from node 1, but node 1 is not reachable from node 2). In general, a matrix is **reducible** if and only if it is permutation-similar to a block-triangular matrix of the form $\pmatrix{X&Y\\ 0&Z}$, where $X$ and $Z$ are square sub-blocks (of possibly different sizes). So, a matrix is called irreducible if it is not permutation-similar to any block-triangular matrix.